# Вставить в таблицу результаты вставки

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, insert

Есть две таблицы `users` и `sessions`. Необходимо Сначала вставить токен в `users`, получить `id` этой записи и вставить ее в `sessions`. Пробую сделать так:

```sql
insert into "session" (userid) 
values (
    insert into "users" (token) 
    values ('exampleToken') 
    returning id
)
where sid = 'exampleSID';
```

Ругается. Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая моя ошибка в попытке сделать `insert` в таблицу `sessions`, где уже было значение, которое надо просто обновить (`update`). Решил вопрос через оператор `WITH`.

```sql
with a as (
    insert into "users" (token) 
    values ('exampleToken') 
    returning id
)
update "session" set userid = (select id from a)
where "session".sid = 'exampleSID';
```

Comment: Если это не разовая потребность, то на мой взгляд проще создать триггер.

Comment: @PotroNik Тоже об этом думал. Могу попросить помочь с примером? Потому что в дальнейшем тоже понадобится

Answer (score 1):

К сожаление с postgresql давно не работал, поэтому ответ будет общим, для возможности правки.

Триггер должен быть с типом `after(после)` на таблице `users`

Функция:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO session (userid, sid) VALUES (new.id, new.token) ON CONFLICT (userid)
    DO UPDATE SET sid = new.token;
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

Триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER name_triger
AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE name_function();
```

Единственный момент, поле `id` не передается в `insert` в основную БД, но насколько я помню все равно значение будет в триггере, тут тест нужен, желательно на макете(мне к сожалению сейчас негде), либо компетентные люди данного сообщества помогут разобраться.